# Hard crash when calling httr::oauth_service_token() - double free or corruption (fasttop)

Tags: r, httr

I am authorizing an google analytics API using httr on a remote server running linux.  The code has worked flawlessly until now, and it still works on our local machines.  Unfortunately since this is an API authorization, this won't be easily reproducible.

```
endpoints <- httr::oauth_endpoints('google')
secrets <- jsonlite::fromJSON(PATH_TO_JSON_FILE)
scope <- 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics'
token <- httr::oauth_service_token(endpoints, secrets, scope)
```

When running on Rstudio Server, this crashes with an alert which says "R encountered a fatal error. The session was terminated".  No error is printed to the console.

I ran the same code while running R through the terminal (on the remote server) and this time there was a `double free or corruption (fasttop)`error with a lot of text of which I'll print some of.

```
token <- httr::oauth_service_token(endpoint = endpoints,secrets = secrets,scope = scope)

*** Error in `/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000002e5df20 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7fb846b637e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8037a)[0x7fb846b6c37a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7fb846b7053c]
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/openssl/libs/openssl.so(R_base64_encode+0x117)[0x7fb842943557]
/usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so(+0xd2c9c)[0x7fb8471a5c9c]
/usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so(Rf_eval+0x7bd)[0x7fb8471e320d]
/usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so(+0x112cae)[0x7fb8471e5cae]

.... MANY LINES OF THIS AND THEN A NEW SECTION ...

======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 523429                             /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 fd:01 523429                             /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 fd:01 523429                             /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R
0121f000-0343e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7fb83c000000-7fb83c021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb83c021000-7fb840000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb8421dd000-7fb84247e000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 7364                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1
7fb84247e000-7fb84267d000 ---p 002a1000 fd:01 7364                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 

.... MANY LINES OF THIS ALSO AND IT ENDS WITH ....

7ffcf87a9000-7ffcf880a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffcf884f000-7ffcf8852000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffcf8852000-7ffcf8854000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

If it would be helpful to show the whole error, I can do that.  I researched double free or corruption and it seems like its a memory corruption error from the base C code.  A linux tool called valgrind can be used to dig deeper into the these issues and I have output from running the code with valgrind as a debugger, but again it looks like mostly gibberish to me, but I'll edit it in if if someone thinks it could be useful.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue using bigrquery::set_service_token that calls this function within it. I am very surprised that my code suddenly stopped working as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error on some linux machines, I suspect in the openSSL or curl libraries that are provided by the system. I'm using Arch, and simply reverting all my packages by a month fixed this error.

Comment: Which version of the libraries did you rever to?